# Build project compatible with Windows XP, 7 and 10 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

My operating environment: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019
Target PC: Windows xp, Windows 7, Windows 10 (for now, all considered as 64bit)

I want to do a distribution that is not dependent on the target OS. For example, I give only one installer to clients, and they might be able to run the program on Windows xp, Windows 7, or Windows 10.
In Project Properties in Visual Studio 2019 what things should I check for that?
Plus, should I compile and build my project in each target platform?

Comment: Are you using the CRT? Are you willing to postprocess the PE header?

Comment: 2019 doesn't directly support xp, you need to use the 2017 toolset https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-170

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for advice. I checked output program of building Visual Studio 2019 default settings is enabled to run in Windows 7(except adding VC runtime). If so, should I prepare one build setting for Windows 7 and 10, and another build setting only for xp, then build each and provide a total of two versions to the client?

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio 2017 v141_xp toolset in VS2019 , the target platform windows sdk will be modified to sdk 7 automatically.

From [SDK 7](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) description：

> this SDK can be used to develop applications for **Windows 7,**
> **Windows XP**, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008

Although  Windows 7 exe can be opened with compatibility on Windows 10, I recommend preparing separate build settings for Windows 7 and 10.